# How to deploy a class library project without deploying the project's .dll

Tags: visual-studio-2008, padarn

In Visual Studio 2008, is there a way to deploy a Class Library Project without deploying the project's DLL?

Background:

I am using OpenNETCF's [Padarn](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Padarn/tabid/267/Default.aspx) web server. OpenNETCF recommends that we design the Padarn web solution into three different projects -

1. A project for the Padarn server
2. A project for the web pages (the static content such as .aspx, html, css, etc)
3. A project for the Code Behind.

It turns out that, due to how Padarn works, there is no need (that I'm aware of) to deploy the DLL of the project that contains the web pages (static content). The .aspx files are nothing much more than text files that contain an @Page directive which tells the Padarn server which Code Behind class to use to build the actual HTML content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to deploy the static files of a project without deploying the .dll of the project.

The only work around I could come up with was to include the static files/content with another project.

In my case, I had a total of three projects. One of the projects was an .exe, another project was the business logic of the .exe project, and the third project contains static content (txt, html, files).

The only work around I could come up with was to include the static content with one of the two other projects such that there were only a total of two projects.